# Ruby on Rails Group by columns and sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got the following Ruby code in my Rails application:

```
# 1
data.pluck(:total_earnings).sum

# 2
data2 = data.select("restaurant, food_type, city, SUM(total_earnings) as total_earnings")
          .group("restaurant, food_type, city")

data2.pluck("total_earnings").sum
```

`data` and `data2` are ActiveRecord Relations.

Line #1 gives me a larger value than line #2.
I can't understand why this is the case as I'm expecting to get a `total_earnings` value for each `restaurant`, `food_type` and `city` combination. Since I'm adding up these values, aggregating the data, why am I losing values here?

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It might be hard to say without seeing your schema of your table. Any chance your `data.select...` is neglecting a column of `total_earnings`?

Comment: If I open the rails console and do a RestaurantEarnings.column_names, I get the following:
=> ["id", "restaurant", "date", "food_type", "city", "total_earnings"]

I'm leaving out data, because I don't want to group by it. I want my groups to be all the restaurant, food_type, city combinations and to then add up all the earnings across the dates for those groups.